# How to setup android studio to create layout resource files automatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I create a new project , there is not a layout folder in res folder. I need to create it manually. How to setup the android studio to create it automatically ?

I did it manually. Right click on res, -> new -> Android Resource Directory and added layout.

Comment: do you tell me what do you tried while project

Answer (score 1):

you are probably creating a new empty Project, it depends on the version of Android you are using, but in Android Girafa a new project "Empty Views Activity" does have the majority of directories by default.

[image]